# How can i do a PUT with an access key into a google storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-apis-explorer

Is there way to do a PUT or POST into a Google Storage bucket with an API key

In the api explorer there is the ability to test this out with OAUTH and the API key, but the explorer doesn't allow me to use the api

Is this possible?
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket/o/object&key="InsertSomeKey"

OR

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o?uploadType=media&name=testobject&key="InsertSomeKey"

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, first of all, you need to authenticate the account that you need to connect, anyway, you must configure an account for access the bucket, like a user account or service account; then you cant make a petition, this is the API reference:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/

I suggested to do it by code, using the libraries:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: Thanks, i have a service account but i wasn't having any luck. It looks like we will have to use the libraries. Thanks